# MVVMCross After navigating to fragment the layout is not refreshed

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a tabbed application that uses MvxTabsFragmentActivity. 
When I navigate between tabs, there is the correct behaviour but the first time when I try to navigate inside a fragment, the called fragment is not replaced.

I tried to use both IMvxNavigationService and also the classic method, using ShowViewModel but they both act the same.

I also used a custom presenter for showing the fragments, but with or without it, the problem stills the same.

There is the image with the printscreen
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRbbi.jpg

The red highlighted is the fragment where I am navigating to and the black one is the previous fragment.

This is the View that has the button needed for navigation:

```
public class TrackView : MvxFragment<TrackViewModel>
{
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        var view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.track_layout, null);
        var nextButton = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.navigate);
        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<TrackView, TrackViewModel>();
        set.Bind(nextButton).To(vm => vm.NavigateEventCommand);
        set.Apply();

        return view;
    }
}
```

This is its ViewModel:

```
public class TrackViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;

    public TrackViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService)
    {
        this._navigationService = navigationService;
    }

    public IMvxCommand NavigateEventCommand => new MvxAsyncCommand(NavigateCommand);

    private async Task NavigateCommand()
    {
        await _navigationService.Navigate<RegistrationViewModel>();
    }
}
```

This is the View where I am navigating to:

```
public class RegistrationView : MvxFragment
{
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        var view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.registration_layout, null);


        //var set = this.CreateBindingSet<RegistrationView, RegistrationViewModel>();
        //set.Apply();
        return view;
    }
}
```

This is its ViewModel:

```
public class RegistrationViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
}
```

I have also a tabbed Application that uses MvxTabsFragmentActivity, and I am creating the tabs like this:

```
protected override void AddTabs(Bundle args)
{
    this.AddTab<TrackView>(
        args,
        Mvx.IocConstruct<TrackViewModel>(),
        this.CreateTabFor("0", Resource.Drawable.ic_track, "Track"));
    this.AddTab<SendView>(
        args, 
        new SendViewModel(), 
    this.CreateTabFor("1", Resource.Drawable.ic_send, "Send"));
    this.AddTab<ProfileView>(
        args,
        new ProfileViewModel(),
        this.CreateTabFor("2", Resource.Drawable.ic_profile, "Profile"));
    this.AddTab<MoreView>(
        args, 
        new MoreViewModel(),
        this.CreateTabFor("3", Resource.Drawable.ic_more, "More"));
}
```

I have a custom presenter that is registered this way in the main class:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    this.tabHost = this.FindViewById<TabHost>(Android.Resource.Id.TabHost);

    presenter = (DroidPresenter)Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAndroidViewPresenter>();
    var initialFragment = new TrackView() { ViewModel = Mvx.IocConstruct<TrackViewModel>() };
    presenter.RegisterFragmentManager(FragmentManager, initialFragment);
}
```

As I said, with or without the presenter, there is the same behaviour.

I am using MvvmCross 5.7.

Comment: Can you post the code for your Fragments and ViewModels?

Comment: I edited the post, I included also the code.

Comment: I see that after I use navigation, the app opens new threads and maybe this is the what causes my problem.

Comment: Do you any presentation attributes above your fragments?